# Loading a file into hashtable in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, hashtable

I have a dictionary file that contains about 7,000 items. I am quite new to JavaScript. I am wondering is there a Hashtable like data structure in JavaScript? Also, is there a way to read it from a local file without building and starting a server? It appears that trying to load data from a local file is not acceptable to browsers as it violates their security setting.

Comment: You could create a webservice that outputs the file in JSON format. Then have JavaScript make an AJAX call to this webservice. What server are you running?

Comment: In javascript, a plain object : var o = {}; is allready a hash table : access the members with o['someName'] or o.someName From here, it's quite easy to do a loop like o[propertyName] = propertyValue; to fill this dictionary.

Comment: @mister_rampage "`without building and starting a server`"...

Comment: a hhtp request + a simple parsing into an object seems ok.

Comment: @faz So you have an app which is saved to a local folder, and is used locally only? Which OS?

Comment: @faz would this library work for you? http://fsojs.com/

Comment: @Teemu It is not an app... I am doing it as a web page for my visualization class.

Comment: @mister_rampage This looks great! I will try with this library...

Comment: @faz _Web pages_ come from servers...

Comment: @Teemu  Yeah...But I just needed a static web page to use d3.js for visualization....That's why I figured that I might not need a server...

Comment: setting up a web server is a 15 minutes job. i had mamp, on mac os, running in no time.